# jQuery click to toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('*').not('div#user').click(function() {
        $('div#userSettings').hide();
    });
    $('div#user').click(function() {
        $('div#userSettings').toggle();
        $('div#profileSettings').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});
```

I need the `div#userSettings` to be hidden whenever anything but it's button or itself is clicked, and I want it to appear only when I click on the `div#user`.

the `toggleclass` does still work in this, just that the `div#userSettings` does not appear at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop the event propagation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('#userSettings').hide();
    })
    $('#user').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#userSettings').toggle();
        $('#profileSettings').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
    $('#userSettings').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mwgxk/)

Comment: Jep... That worked.. Thank you very much. I will mark this as answer as soon as it lets me :D